# Very Big JSON (92,000 rows) does not load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, datatable

I have a simple function to return my datatable as JSON from c# using the Serializer as follows -

```
public static string ConvertToJSON (DataTable dt)
{
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new                     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
}
rows.Add(row);
}
return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

Which I use as follows

```
return ConvertToJSON(objDataTable);
```

where objDataTable is my Datatable

I also have

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strArrMapObject, Formatting.None);
```

where I am using the library Newtonsoft.Json and strArrMapObject is an Itemarray built from objDataTable

Both the above methods work fine for small datatables and I get the output like this -

```
["11-06-2014 00:00:00","17:45:00","Beta","357637031475680","404490480844084","78","IN","","8143888569","48"]
```

But when I do it for a big datatable (eg. 92,000 rows), nothing happens!

There is no response and there is no timeout error also.

So when I use

```
alert (response);
```

[in Javascript] or even

```
document.getElementById('divDataHolder').innerHTML = response;
```

[in Javascript]

absolutely nothing happens!

Please help!

Comment: Why on Earth are you trying to serialise your WHOLE database into JSON... Just WHY?! :-S There is never a good reason to do this. You probably want to page your data or be more specific, never just dump your database on the client!

Comment: Hi Belogix
Thank you for your response. I agree the thought did cross my mind and I probably need to relook at my approach. Basically there is a date filter in my solution. So essentially the customer can select a date-range to retrieve the data. Ideally, he should be able to select any date-range. But do you suggest I limit the date range? (as per day, the average number of rows could be around 500 in my application)

Comment: My suggestion is that you limit the amount that you show the client at any one-time. So, although you might get 500 records that match your filter you only return say 50 records at a time. Then the user can click the NEXT PAGE arrow and show next 50 and so on. @Margus is saying the same thing... This is a common approach / pattern to handling large amounts of data. Google results is a perfect example of this. Humans can't cope with 92K+ records in one chunk anyway! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your request so that you can ask

```
select 100 rows page 1 // selects items 1-100
select 100 rows page 2 // selects items 101-200
```

This would solve more then 1 problem.

```
public static string ConvertToJSON (DataTable dt, int page = 0, int count = 100)    
//...
foreach (DataRow o in dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(page * count).Take(count))
```

Edit: You can use following method to get Json

```
//add reference System.Data
//add reference System.Web.extensions
//add reference System.Web.DataTableExtensions
public static string ConvertToJson(DataTable dt, int page = 0, int count = 100)
{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(page * count).Take(count).ToList())
    {
        rows.Add(dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => dr[col]));
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

Comment: Hi Margus, Thank you for your response. Since, I am going to be using the data for geo-mapping the movement history of a particular individual; so paging as such may not work. Is there any temporary data storage method client-side (like the Datarepeater in ASP.NET) or is there a jquery grid which I can build up slowly and then use particular rows from the grid for my geo-mapping purpose?

Comment: Thank you to both Belogix and Margus! I started coding after many years :) I think I have to sit back and rethink my approach to the solution. Thanks for showing the way! (Looking forward to getting more reps to vote up your answer sometime soon)

Comment: Haha! It took 6 years for me to be able to upvote! Thanks a lot! :)